# How to install a Visual Studio project template in a non-user-specific location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2012

When I install my .zip visual studio project template into `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates` it works, but this is a user-specific directory.

Is there any way to install such a project for every user in the machine? Something like a C:\Program Files\ location I mean. I've tried several "template" directories in the VS path inside Program Files but none of them worked.

How to install locally a .zip project template for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx):

> By default, Visual Studio searches two locations for project and item templates.
>
> **Installed Templates**: By default, templates installed together with the product are located in: `\<VisualStudioInstallationDirectory>\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\<Language>\<Locale>\`
>
> **Custom Templates**: By default, custom templates are located in: `\My Documents\Visual Studio <Version>\Templates\ProjectTemplates\<Language>\`