# How to install a template in Visual Studio 2017 manually?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to install the CocosSharp Templates into VS 2017, but for some reason the download is so slow  (1KB/s), I downloaded the template from outside VS as a zip file on my machine, and I need to install it in VS.. any help?

Comment: what format is the file?

Comment: As I mentioned, zip file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a Visual Studio project template in a non-user-specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942794/how-to-install-a-visual-studio-project-template-in-a-non-user-specific-location)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the zip file in the templates folder

`\My Documents\Visual Studio Version\Templates\ItemTemplates\Language\`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx